# Centering symbol displaced by underbraced text and broken underbrace

Tags: horizontal-alignment, braces

I have the following code:

```
$$
\underbrace{ \{\varphi\}\cup\Delta_M\cup\{p_M\} }_{\text{Finito e instasifacible.} } \subseteq \underbrace{\Gamma\cup\Delta_{M+1}}_{\text{Finitamente satisfacible.}}
$$
```

And it looks like this in my document:

[image]

I have two issues wit this, the first is that I want the subseteq symbol to be centered, between the two expression, and the second is that the second underbrace looks a bit broken, but I imagine there's no way to fix that.

Comment: Maybe, instead of using $$, you may use the align environment and so putting in your equation line the &s to balance it.

Comment: @PMC1234 I tried putting &s after and before the symbol, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't reproduce your problem with braces. Regarding centering of symbol: it is easy to center, if you broke "Finitamente satisfacible" into two lines:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage[active,displaymath,tightpage]{preview}
    \setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

\begin{document}
\[
\underbrace{ \{\varphi\}\cup\Delta_M\cup\{p_M\} }_{\text{Finito e instasifacible.} } \subseteq \underbrace{\Gamma\cup\Delta_{M+1}}_{\substack{\text{Finitamente}\\ \text{satisfacible.}}}
\]
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** Since you persist to have text under braces in one line ... than only what you can do, is increase the space between left term and subseteq symbol:

[image]

For this, the equation is:

```
\[
\underbrace{ \{\varphi\}\cup\Delta_M\cup\{p_M\} }_{\text{Finito e instasifacible.} } 
    \qquad\subseteq \underbrace{\Gamma\cup\Delta_{M+1}}_{\text{Finitamente satisfacible.}}
\]
```

**Edit (2):** For completness, I will prefer the folowing solution:

[image]

```
\[
\underbrace{ \{\varphi\}\cup\Delta_M\cup\{p_M\} }_{\substack{\text{Finito e}\\ \text{instasifacible.}}}  
    \subseteq 
\underbrace{\Gamma\cup\Delta_{M+1}}_{\substack{\text{Finitamente}\\ \text{satisfacible.}}}
\]
```

Comment: I think the broken underbrace might be some software problem, as I checked on some printed documents which showed this same problem on my pc and they look ok in paper. Regarding the spacing, I'd rather keep the "Finitamente satisfacible." (it kind of ruins the formatting on the following paragraphs) in one line: I don't mind if there's a big space between the two symbolic expression, I just want the subset symbol to be a bit more centered.

Comment: Different people, different tastes ..., see if added example in my answer is what you looking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Zarko, your answer is very complete. You've also changed my mind, I'm gonna go with your solution (even if it takes adjusting some paragraphs!).

Answer (score 2):

You also could use `\underbrace\overbrace` and `\mathclap`. I give an example with `\underbracket/\oberbracket` (defined in `mathtools`):

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{mathtools}


\begin{document}

\[
\underbracket[0.6pt][0.6ex]{\{\varphi\}\cup\Delta_M\cup\{p_M\} }_{\text{Finito e instasifacible.} } \subseteq \overbracket[0.6pt][0.6ex]{\Gamma\cup\Delta_{M+1}}^{\mathclap{\text{Finitamente satisfacible.}}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh yes! Messed up again with my clipboard manager. Thanks for pointing it. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

The answer given by @Zarco is very complete it I'll give another option. The problem seems to be the text under the braces. Here is my alternative :

```
   \[
\underbrace{\{\varphi\}\cup\Delta_M\cup\{p_M\}}_{\text{Finito e}\atop\text{insatisfacible}} \subseteq
\underbrace{\Gamma\cup\Delta_{M+1}}_{\text{Finitamente} \atop
\text{satisfacible}}
\]
```